# What does d:IsPrototypingComposition mean in WPF/Silverlight projects using Blend SketchFlow?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, sketchflow

I can't find any documentation on this anywhere. Does anyone know what the `d:IsPrototypingComposition` attribute means and does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a design time property (the d: prefix) that allows Blend to show extra UI/Adorners on instances of SketchFlow Composition screens.

If you remove it, you will see the extra adorner in the upper left corner of the instance disappear.